# Product Feed empty with no reasons

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog, products, google-product-feeds

I did a mistake today and deleted all the "Product feeds" today instead of generating them.

I'm re-creating them and it's working for France, UK and Germany.
For no reason it is not working for USA and Switzerland while there are many products in the store :

[image]

The feed is just a duplicate of a working one with an other store (For the example: USA).

Why is the feed empty ?

Answer (score 0):

On Magento 1.9 the feeds generation do not fail when there is problems with variables.

In my case the tax variable was configured for France but not for Switzerland.